# Can a Swift init be made available only for ObjectiveC?

Tags: swift, objective-c, interop

Suppose I have a Swift class

```
@objcMembers class C: NSObject {
  let range: ClosedRange<Int>

  init(range: ClosedRange<Int>) {
    self.range = range
    super.init()
  }

  convenience init(min: Int, max: Int) {
    self.init(range: min...max)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to make the `convenience init` available only from Objective-C, so that the API will be smaller?

Comment: Yes, but then you need to write your init in Objective-C (not Swift) and possibly mark it with `NS_SWIFT_UNAVAILABLE` 9depends on usage really - is it public, etc)

Comment: I hesitate to even suggest this, but you could replace the convenience initialiser with a static factory function that has an unpleasant name (e.g. `makeObjectiveCInstance`) and returns a new `C`. That doesn’t hide it from Swift, but makes it much harder to use accidentally and less likely to appear in autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: With functions that are not `init` I would have a swift-only `func getC(range:) -> C`, and a `@objc(getC) func _getC(min:max:) -> C`. Not optimal, the underscore is widely used in this context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can expose the method to Objective-C runtime and make it `private` at the same time. This however requires you to introduce the private method's interface yourself (ideally by extending the auto-generated interface, rather than introducing a separate class declaration). Your swift class should look something like this:

```swift
@objc(TDWSwiftObject)
class SwiftObject: NSObject {

    let range: ClosedRange<Int>

    init(range: ClosedRange<Int>) {
        self.range = range
        super.init()
    }

    @objc private convenience init(min: Int, max: Int) {
        self.init(range: min...max)
    }

}
```

And then add the missing Objective-C parts as a class category:

```objc
@interface TDWSwiftObject (Private)

- (instancetype)initWithMin:(int)min max:(int)max;

@end
```

Now your Swift code won't be able to refer to the constructor (because it has `private` access modifier), while the Objective-C code can use it just fine.

Comment: Agh... More trouble than its worth, I'm afraid. Wish there was a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot hide it from autocomplete, if that was your goal.

What you can do is:

```
@available(swift, obsoleted: 1.0)
convenience init ( min: Int, max: Int ) 
{
```

Now trying to call that method from Swift is a hard error and autocomplete will not suggest that init by default, but it's still in the list.